Swagger Codegen not annotating request body parameters correctly
I am generating a Java 21 API for RestEasy* with Swagger Codegen (using io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.54). One of the endpoints has a request body which is a file (application/octet-stream). The generated interface annotates the body parameter as @Parameter rather than @RequestBody and I don't understand why. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?
At runtime a call to an API based on this, with Content-Type: application/octet-stream, fails:
RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: jakarta.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class java.lang.Object of content type: application/octet-stream

The relevant section of my swagger.yml looks like this:
      "/v1/blah":
        post:
          summary: "Blah"
          operationId: "blah"
          requestBody:
            required: true
            content:
              application/octet-stream:
                schema:
                  type: string
                  format: binary

The Codegen plugin (in Maven) runs with the following configuration:
<configuration>
    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/swagger/swagger.yml</inputSpec>
    <language>jaxrs-resteasy-eap</language>
    <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
    <apiPackage>[...]</apiPackage>
    <modelPackage>[...]</modelPackage>
    <configOptions>
        <useTags>true</useTags>
        <useSwaggerFeature>true</useSwaggerFeature>
        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
        <java8>true</java8>
        <jakarta>true</jakarta>
        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
        <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
        <sourceFolder>[...]</sourceFolder>
        <implFolder>[...]</implFolder>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>

The generated interface method looks like this:
@Path("/v1")
@jakarta.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaResteasyEapServerCodegen", date = "2024-06-11T10:33:51.930963+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]")
public interface V1Api {
    @POST
    @Path("/blah")
    @Consumes({ "application/octet-stream" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @Operation(summary = "blah", description = "", security = [...], tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = [...])
    Response blah(@Parameter(description = "" ,required=true) Object body,@Context SecurityContext securityContext);

*I'm actually using Quarkus 3.8.2, which pulls in RestEasy 6.2.7.Final, but I don't think that's relevant since it's the generated API that seems to be wrong.

@Parameter and @RequestBody the reason the code generated is using parameter is likely because it is the JaxRS rather than the Spring specific RequestBody now the error you are seeing is likely because Object type for body (it should be byte[] or InputStream). So try to add to your schema definition x-java-type: "byte[]" below the format same level and see what happens, this is vendor extension not sure if the libraries you are using supports it though it doesn't hurt to test it. The other options is either rewrite the template or manually change the generated code.

Thanks @JorgeCampos. It doesn't appear that the Generator I'm using has support for this, but I eventually elected to change the generated code (this is only a prototype) to use InputStream and now it works fine.
